# Adding Grid to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, grid, wpfdatagrid

I want to add `Grid` (may be containing images, buttons, or any other controls) to `DataGrid`, programmatically using C#(WPF). I have also try using these codes for test:

```
public class DataGridItem
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public Grid Stats;
}
```

, xaml codes as for `DataGrid` columns:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="h1" Binding="{Binding Path}"/>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="h2">
```

, and codes behind as (in a button):

```
var g = new Grid()
{
    Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black 
};

var tb = new TextBlock()
{
     Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
};

g.Children.Add(tb);

Dg.Items.Add(
    new DataGridItem()
    {
        Path = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
        Stats = g
    });
```

I try to set `Binding` for `h2` column but I cannot because it is a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Is there any way to set binding for `h2` as `h1` column?

Or, is there any way to add `Grid` to `DataGrid` programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="h2">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresent Content="{Binding Stats}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to set binding for h2 as h1 column?

No.

> Or, is there any way to add Grid to DataGrid programmatically?

You could create a `CellTemplate` programmatically:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn h2 = Dg.Columns[1] as DataGridTemplateColumn;
const string Xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><ContentControl Content=\"{Binding Stats}\" /></DataTemplate>";
h2.CellTemplate = XamlReader.Parse(Xaml) as DataTemplate;
```

Sample XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Dg">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="h1" Binding="{Binding Path}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="h2" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```